# Alternative of Thread.sleep in selenium

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

In selenium testing framework I am using thread.sleep(40000). I have a requirement not to use thread.sleep()or its alternative fluent wait or any kind of wait, and keep your script engaged anyhow so that script will pick particular element after that some interval until that element actually appears on that page. Hence error wont be thrown while accessing the element. Do you have any suggestion how can I keep my script engaged for few miliseconds without using any wait ?

Comment: why would you not use explicit wait? Any reason behind why you are forbidden yo use waits? And also Thread.sleep is a big no.

Comment: Do you and/or whoever is placing the requirement to not use waits understand how waits work? Sleep is bad because it waits X amount of seconds and does nothing in the meantime. Explicit waits (e.g. WebDriverWait and FluentWait) are a good practice and should be used. They poll the page every 500ms (by default) to see if the condition is fulfilled. If it is, then the wait ends and the script continues. If the condition is not fulfilled by the timeout, then a timeout exception is thrown. So the script is still "engaged" even when using WebDriverWait.

Comment: You want to have an overall timeout... you don't want your script to get stuck in an infinite waiting period because the condition never succeeds. That's why using WebDriverWait is a good practice. It polls while it's waiting for the timeout but there still is an overall timeout so that if doesn't succeed after a certain period of time, it times out and fails the test.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed description JeffC. I will try to implement this and update here the consequences :) . The wait is not getting approved by client due to script running on 100's of instances and may slowdown server, not sure though. I will dig into more and update here.

Answer (score -1):

I use this code. You can add try catch with timeOutException.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By.*;

By element = new ById("id");
long timeout;

WebElement webElement =(WebElement)(new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), timeout)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));
```

Comment: The `By` declaration should be `By locator = By.id("id");`. It's not an element at this point so the name would be confusing. Also, I'm not sure where you are getting `new ById("id")` unless that's some custom code because it's not standard Selenium. You also don't need to cast the `.until()` return as a `WebElement` because it's already a `WebElement`. You also never declared the timeout so this code would throw an exception. But most of all, OP asked for a way without a wait and `WebDriverWait` is a wait.